# get a specified line in variable and Find all indexes of a specified word from a variable in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is an example:
Hello

How are you, How about your friend.

I am fine

Take Care

So here i want the second line as output("How are you, How about your friend.") and then get the index number of "How".
so finally i want the index numbers for How = 0 and 3 (Since there are two occurrences.

Comment: You should indicate what you have tried thus far. Please refer to sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
function testIt99() {
  var textTest = "How are you, How about your friend.";
  //remove commas
  textTest = textTest.replace(",", "");
  Logger.log('textTest: ' + textTest);
  textTest = textTest.replace(".", "");
  Logger.log('textTest: ' + textTest);

  //put all words into an array
  var arrayOfWords = textTest.split(" ");
  Logger.log('textTest: ' + textTest);

  var arrayOfIndexes = [];
  var i=0;
  for (i=0;i<arrayOfWords.length;i+=1) {
    if (arrayOfWords[i]==="How") {
      arrayOfIndexes.push(i)
    };
  };

  Logger.log("Indexes of 'How' are: " + arrayOfIndexes)
};
```